# Using WebServiceGatewaySupport to handle requests to multiple webservices

Tags: soap, spring-ws

I'm using spring-ws-core to build a SOAP client. For this I'm extending WebServiceGatewaySupport to make the service calls.

```
public class WeatherClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {
...
    public WeatherResponse getCityForecastByZip(String zipCode) {
        GetCityForecastByZIP request = new GetCityForecastByZIP();
        request.setZIP(zipCode);

        GetCityForecastByZIPResponse response = (GetCityForecastByZIPResponse) this.getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request,
                new SoapActionCallback("http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityForecastByZIP"));

        return response;
    }
...
}
```

Spring configuration is pretty straightforward

```
@Configuration
public class WebServicesConfiguration {

    private static final String WEATHER_SERVICE_DEFAULT_URI = "...";


    @Bean(name = "servicesMarshaller")
    public Jaxb2Marshaller servicesMarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("some.package");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public WeatherClient weatherService(@Qualifier("servicesMarshaller") Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        WeatherClient client = new WeatherClient(WEATHER_SERVICE_DEFAULT_URI);
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }

}
```

This works just fine for a single web service. Now, suppose that I have many similar web services, but each one has it's own .wsdl specification and URI. I know that I can make a service call through the spring WebServiceTemplate and specify the URI to use. So my idea was to use a single WebServiceGatewaySupport to handle all the calls to the different services. In each call, I would pass the soap action, the corresponding request, if any, and the web service URL. My application is suppose to run in a multi-threaded environment.

Is this a good practice to use a single WebServiceGatewaySupport to handle concurrent calls to different URIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to the `WebServiceGatewaySupport` source code, the short asnwer: yes, it is OK to use it for different URLs, as well as the underlying `WebServiceTemplate` is thread-safe.

Your implementation will be thread-safe too, if you don't save some state between requests.

Comment: It is ok you said. Can you elaborate why it isn't better than ok?

Comment: All hard work is delegated to the `WebServiceTemplate` and for it it doesn't matter, if you use different URLs or the same, which might be a default one. So, of course it is better to have just only one instance for `WebServiceTemplate` to avoid excess GC work. The same rule is for your target `WebServiceGatewaySupport`. However I have never used it: `WebServiceTemplate` is always enough.